# POST запрос отправка коментариев

Tags: android, json, post

Нужно реализовать отправку отзывов на сервер после авторизации. Авторизацию прохожу получаю токен, и тут возникла проблема с отправкой отзыва, передаю POST на - (http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/reviews/1), запросом в теле JSON которого:

```
 {
  "rate": "5",
  "text": "Lorem"
 }
```

пример ответа:

```
 {
   "review_id": 5
 }
```

Но отзыв не доходит. Есть у меня догадки что нужно что то делать с этим токеном чтобы отзывы доходили.
Ниже код отправки POST запроса.

```
 public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {

String b = "product1";

Context c;
EditText Etext;
EditText Erate;
Button sendRevBtn;
String textRev;
String rateRev;
String url = "http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/reviews/1";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.products_sign);

    TextView productName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productListName1);
    TextView productText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productListText1);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnailImage1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fname");
    String text1 = intent.getStringExtra("text");
    String token = intent1.getExtras().getString("token");
    Toast.makeText(ActivityTwo.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    productName1.setText(fName);
    productText.setText(text1);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
        Bitmap bitmam = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmam);
    }
 //Лист для коментов
    ListView listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.comentsList);
    ComentsArrayAdapter  adapter;
    Coments2ArrayAdapter adapter2;
    adapter = new ComentsArrayAdapter(this);
    adapter2 = new Coments2ArrayAdapter(this);
   if (productName1.getText().equals(b)) {
       listV.setAdapter(adapter);
   }else listV.setAdapter(adapter2);

     //тело Пост запроса коментариев
    //
    //
    c = this;
    Etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    Erate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_rate);
    sendRevBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_rev);

    sendRevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            textRev = Etext.getText() + "";
            rateRev = Erate.getText() + "";

            if ( textRev .length() == 0 || rateRev.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if ( textRev.length() > 0 && rateRev.length() > 0) {
                //Do networking
                Networking n = new Networking();
                n.execute(url, Networking.NETWORK_STATE_COMENTS);
                Toast.makeText(c, "Review send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
//AsyncTask good for long running tasks
public class Networking extends AsyncTask {

    public static final int NETWORK_STATE_COMENTS = 1;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        getJson((String) params[0], (Integer) params[1]);
        return null;
    }
}

private void getJson(String url, int state) {
    //Do a HTTP POST, more secure than GET
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    boolean valid = false;

    switch (state) {
        case Networking.NETWORK_STATE_COMENTS:
            //Building key value pairs to be accessed on web
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", textRev));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rate", rateRev));

            valid = true;
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unknown state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if (valid == true) {
        //Reads everything that comes from server
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(entity);

            //Send off to server
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            //Reads response and gets content
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            //Read back server output
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        decodeResultIntoJson(stringBuffer.toString());
    } else {
    }
}

private void decodeResultIntoJson(String response) {
    if (response.contains("error")) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            String error = jo.getString("error");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);

        String success = jo.getString("success");
        String message = jo.getString("message");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

В документации есть только это:

POST /api/reviews/1/ - поститься отзыв о продукте с идентификатором .
Пример запроса:

```
   {
    "rate": 5,
   "text": "Lorem"
   }
```

Пример ответа:

```
  {
   "review_id": 5
  }
```

GET /api/reviews/1/ - возвращает список отзывов для продукта с идентификатором .
   Пример ответа:

```
 {
  "id": 10,
  "product": 1,
  "created_by": {
  "id": 1,
  "username": "user"
 },
   "rate": 0,
   "text": "ipsum"
 },
```

Comment: А как отзыв может не дойти, если вы получили ответ?

Comment: Если бы он доходил правильно, то на "http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/reviews/1" создавался бы новый объект с моими строками rate и text, но этого не происходит. Ответ я написал как пример каким он должен быть.

Comment: а адрес запроса точно верный? просто по этому адресу на GET запрос в ответ приходит список отзывов. А есть вообще документация по API?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос выше, там написано что было в документации.

Comment: Если верить POSTMAN'у , то запрос выполняется некорректно и в ответ приходит не JSON с ответом, а XML с логом ошибки на сервере

Comment: То есть в теле запроса нужно передавать другие строки, чтобы он доходил правильно?

Comment: Это я уже не знаю, но запрос не выполняется как надо